# PHP ActiveRecord automatically formatting date

Tags: php, phpactiverecord

So it seems that PHP **ActiveRecord** is formatting the update timestamp (for me anyway)

*When I print the updated date, it displays:*

`Wed, 05 Jun 2013 21:14:48 +0200`

*Where as in the DB I've got:*

`2013-06-23 20:04:18`

Just to be a 100% certain I used PDO to retrieve the record it displayed exactly the format I see in the DB.

Any idea why this automatic formatting might happen? and if there is a way to correct it?

Thanks.

### EDIT

Ok, so I discovered how to manipulate it:

`$records->updated->format('Y-m-d');`

However, I'd still like to know why it happens and if there is a way to set it by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

phpactiverecord retrieves it and stores it in an object that extends `DateTime`.

Normally you could do `->format($yourformat)` for any `DateTime` object, but for the `phpactiverecord` child you get a default format that gets used if you do not supply one.

This extension also has a `toString()` function that calls this `format()`, so you get the default format (which you can set in this same class by the way).

Take a look at the `DateTime.php` class provided by PHPActiveRecord to find out more, but this is what happens:

```
 class DateTime extends \DateTime{
    public static $DEFAULT_FORMAT = 'rfc2822';
    //array with formats here

    public function format($format=null){
        return parent::format(self::get_format($format));
    }

    public static function get_format($format=null){
        //get default format if nothing is provided
    }

    public function __toString(){
        //gets called when you use the object as a string
        return $this->format();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this globally

**Code-Snippet**

```
ActiveRecord\Connection::$datetime_format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
ActiveRecord\DateTime::$DEFAULT_FORMAT = 'db';
```